# WP 4.x + Jetpack Installation Error: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

When installing jetpack from the auto install screen, I wasn't able to get it working to an internal 500 error related to this PHP setting.

HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Answer (score 0):

After a while trying different configurations with no luck, I decided to extract the zip and install manually and it installed correctly with no problems so far.